# Python script to crawl a website that needs logging in using Google, Yahoo, or Facebook

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

So I have this Python script ready that is able to pull certain information pertaining to my interest from a website. Nothing heavy, just politely pulling some content from the website.

However, the problem I am facing is that this website needs you to first log in using a Google, Yahoo, or Facebook account. So it goes like this: You visit the website, you try to 'search', it redirects you to login using one of the 3 methods. If I select Yahoo, it opens a new small window where I'm taken to the Yahoo login page. After I have logged in, this small window closes and the website is redirected to a "logged in" state. I can then make the search for the content.

I want my Python script to be able to login using one of these methods, and then I have written the code for 'web scraping' that will pull some content from the website.

Could any one please point me to the easiest way I can make my script use one of these authentication methods?

Comment: Would you use only one account so you could hard code the authentication or do you have a list of users?

Comment: I will use only one account. Yes, I will hard code the credentials into the script for now.